# IBM SDK 7 for Non IBM Windows machines?

Tags: java

IBM SDK Java Technology Edition Version 7 are available for their AIX platform and the Linux platform. Are NON-IBM machine with 32-64 bit Windows supported by IBM SDK 7? I have heard 32 bit runtime environment for windows is only available for IBM Systems as a separate download, a BIOS check verifies that it is an IBM system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is true.

A non-official way to get IBM JDK 7 is to download and install [WebSphere 8](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ws/was/) for Windows platform (trial version) and [latest fix pack](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27004980#ver80) because it may contain JDK updates too.

As a result, you will find IBM JDK 7 in `AppServer/java7` directory you can zip and copy to any other Windows system whatever its underlying hardware. No registration key required, you just have to add bin into your `PATH` and eventually set `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

Of course, that operation works and it is mainly used for developer workstations but you have to contact IBM if you expect to get support about running productively JDK 7 on Windows.

Comment: I have downloaded and installed WASv8.5, and IBM Java SDK 6 (SDK 6) is shipped with websphere application server v8.5 (WAS v8.5) as the default SDK. IBM JAVA SDK 7(SDK 7) is packaged as an extension offering to WAS v8.5. An additional repository is required for IM installation. I have downloaded oracle java 7 and created a property file and placed inside property folder of AppServer and java7 folder in AppServer. but i am wondering how IBM SDK 7 is difference from Oracle version of java

Comment: I guess it is different the same way it was for Java 6. The JVM itself is a different code base called `J9` (not `Hotspot`), then some API implementations are completely IBM specific like `JSSE`, Kerberos stack...

Answer (score 2):

A smaller and simpler download, although only for 64-bit Java (windows and linux), is available here: https://developer.ibm.com/assets/wasdev/#asset/runtimes-webprofile7-ibm-java  This is a zip file (about 200 MB) and requires no login to download.  It is packaged with the Liberty Java EE runtime - this package has the features for the Java EE 7 full spec.

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: I know that this question is old, but it's one of the top results for a google search of "where to download 32-bit IBM JRE for windows". So I'm contributing my answer in the event it might help others.

PREREQUISITES: An IBMid login to use on the support section of the IBM site.

If you have an IBM support account, you can download Fixpak 9 for IBM 8.5.5.9: WebSphere Application Server V8.5.5. Make sure you read IBM's terms and conditions before downloading anything. IANAL.

This package is dated February 25, 2016 .

It is available from this intial URL:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24041819#SDK80

Scroll down to
"IBM WebSphere SDK Java Technology Edition V8.0 for full profile and Liberty"

and you will find
Windows:    8.0.2.10-WS-IBMWASJAVA-Win.zip 
Clicking on that link will lead to an IBMid page to identify yourself, and then you can download this "300-MB hairball" (Scott McNeally dixit) 8.0.2.10-WS-IBMWASJAVA-Win.zip file.

When you unpack that 8.0.2.10-WS-IBMWASJAVA-Win.zip hairball, you will find the 32-bit JRE as a file named
com.ibm.websphere.jdk8.32bit.jre_003_windows.x8632_x_8.0.2010.201602250020.zip
it is insied the \native subfolder of the ZIP archive.

Hope this helps